# Pass an argument though makefile linux/unix command line in C

Tags: c, linux, makefile, command-line-arguments

my makefile is:

```
CFLAGS=-g

all:        mcast_client mcast_server

mcast_client:   mcast_client.o $(ARG1)

mcast_server:   mcast_server.o

clean:
        rm -f mcast_client mcast_server mcast_client.o mcast_server.o
```

in the command window i type,

```
$ make ARG1=hello, world!
```

is this correct?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As it stands, you're saying '`mcast_client` is not up to date unless files `hello,` and `world!` are also up to date, which is unlikely to be what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$ make ARG1="hello, world!"
```

Comment: Why would an env var (which can be overridden by a value in the makefile) be better than an explicit (un-overrideable) command-line assignment?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well I would think it is more readable because with a target after `make` call, this would separate variable and target.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is there a semantic difference between the two that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes there is a difference. The `ARG1=xxx make` notation uses a shell feature to set an environment variable ARG1 for the duration of the `make` command.  `make` will use the env var if it is neither over-ridden on the command line nor specified in the makefile (but you can use `make -e` so that the environment is more important than what it says in the makefile).  The `make ARG1=xxx` notation sets the macro unconditionally and it cannot be overridden by the makefile or the environment.  Much of the time, the net result is the same.  However, the semantics are, in fact, quite different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK, thanks for the explanation. I removed the second proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Your invocation `make ARG1="hello, world!"` is almost correct (but the quotes are needed for the shell), but your `Makefile` is not.

A more realistic approach would be to pass the message as a preprocessor macro.

Assume `hello.c` contains (in the middle of some C function)

```
  printf("%s\n", MESSAGE);
```

Then you could have a `Makefile` rule like

```
  hello.o: hello.c
       $(COMPILE.c) -DMESSAGE=\"$(MSG)\" $< -o $@
```

<sup>The quotes are backslashed because the preprocessor macro `MESSAGE` should have quotes.</sup>

And finally you could invoke

```
  make "MSG=hello friend"
```

<sup>Beware that this won't work if `MSG` contains quotes `"` or backslashes `\` .... In the command above the quotes are interpreted by the shell...</sup>

Notice that you are supposed to invoke `make` with the same command every time... (since `hello.o` won't be rebuilt if the `MSG` has changed).

BTW, take the habit of *always* compiling with `-Wall`  so

```
  CFLAGS= -Wall -g
```

and look at predefined rules of `make` given by `make -p`

Consider using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (notably invoked with `-x`) to debug tricky or complex `Makefile`-s.